# Динамические перменные в .gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-runner, yml

У меня есть бранча Deltadepl_docker, с таким же названием была добавлена перменная в GItlab CI\CD variables
Как я могу вызвать переменную по названию бранчи?

Мой .gitlab-ci.yml

```
variables:
  SLACK_PROD_CHANNEL: "test1"
  SLACK_CHANNEL_FOR_ERRORS: "test1"
  PMD_PATH: "/opt/pmd/pmd-bin-6.53.0/bin"
  TEST_COVERAGE_LEVEL: "85"
  SCA_PLACE: "/opt/for_analys"
  HOME_OF_SCRIPT: "/opt/delta_bot"
  RULESET: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/__PMD/GOLD_ruleset.xml"
  FORCE_APP: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/force-app"
  NEED_TEST: "0"
  TEST_AFTER: "0"
  LIST_OF_FAILURE: 'data'
  LINK: ${"$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH"}


preparing_deploy:
  stage: prepare
  image: 
  script:
    - echo $SLACK_PROD_TOKEN #1
    - echo $SLACK_PROD_CHANNEL #2
    - echo $SLACK_CHANNEL_FOR_ERRORS #3
    - echo $CI_PROJECT_DIR #4
    - echo $PMD_PATH #5
    - echo $TEST_COVERAGE_LEVEL #6
    - echo $SCA_PLACE #7
    - echo $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH #8
    - echo $HOME_OF_SCRIPT #9
    - echo $RULESET #10
    - echo $FORCE_APP #11
    - echo $NEED_TEST #12
    - echo $TEST_AFTER #13
    - echo $LIST_OF_FAILURE #14
    - echo $"$LINK" #15
    - echo $CI_COMMIT_SHA #16
    - python3 /opt/delta_bot/before_deploy_Parse_Json.py $SLACK_PROD_TOKEN $SLACK_PROD_CHANNEL $SLACK_CHANNEL_FOR_ERRORS $CI_PROJECT_DIR $PMD_PATH $TEST_COVERAGE_LEVEL $SCA_PLACE $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH $HOME_OF_SCRIPT $RULESET $FORCE_APP $NEED_TEST $TEST_AFTER $LIST_OF_FAILURE $LINK $CI_COMMIT_SHA
  only:
    - Deltadepl_docker
```

Я пытался обозначить это след способами

```
LINK: $"$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" 
LINK: ${"$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH"}
LINK: "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH"
```

Хочу полусить след
LINK: $Deltadepl_docker
И так с каждой бранчой ибо там будут креды для доступа на env

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ прост:

```
  LINK: "${$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}"
```